# How to take accurate print from RDLC report without saving as pdf

Tags: rdlc

I arrange the textbox in rdlc in correct width and height for pre printed page printing. As I take in pdf the alignment of all the labels come correct but I want to take the same without the file getting saved as pdf in system.
In short I don't want to take pdf but still want accurate print like pdf without the file getitng downloaded

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpz0D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by rendering the report viewer into pdf and directly will be displayed in PDF Print

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string contentType;
string encoding;
string extension;

//Export the RDLC Report to Byte Array.
byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out contentType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

// Open generated PDF.
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = contentType;
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Refer
https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/110559/Export-PDF-from-RDLC-Report-and-open-in-Browser-on-Button-Click-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet/